# Negotiating salary weighting

Tags: salary, negotiation, relocation

Firstly, forgive me if this has already been posted but I looked and couldn't find anything specifically about salary weighting, If so ill remove.

I recently relocated to a new city in the same job (I just moved to a different office) where it is considerably more expensive to live. My company agreed to pay me a weighting for my role based on my new city vs my old one. This move was was discussed very early in the interview process (with 5 directors of the company) and I was offered the right support and permission to do it.

My employer and I agreed how I'd to go about the move was to let my LM and Head of Department know that I was looking for a house (as I said they knew about it anyway, it was just a matter of when), which was acknowledged at the time. Then to tell them when we have one to move into, again this was agreed at the time. This then gave my employer a 2 month definitive deadline of my intentions to move, as well as a start date in the new office and the chance for them to work out the HR related admin and salary. All of this was discussed through various means, chats, messages and emails and agreed. So when I found a place I notified them about it to get the ball rolling.

I spotted a figure in our HR software one day before I was told in any capacity what it would be so I approached my Head of Department about it. The figure my HoD gave me (same as in the HR software), in a "quick chat", I profoundly disagree with but they say there is no wiggle room and that its final, despite my attempt to negotiate when presenting research that I had done, I got a flat "No".

I had done research knowing this chat would happen eventually. I had looked at various things, salary surveys, similar job specs, recruiter polls, glassdoor, asking a few friends I know who have done the same thing.

There are a couple of factors to bear in mind: 
1. There salary range for my role in the industry is broad, so broad that its difficult to pin down where I sit. 
2. My company tell me im at the top of my banding. 
3. The research I have got suggests it should be more. 
4. I really like the job and place I work, this just casts a negative light on it.

In around 1-2 weeks I have my appraisal and I have a feeling that this will be brought up as it will be the official platform that they will have to tell me about the increase in the presence of HR.

My question(s) is:

1. How do I respond to them asking if im happy with it or want to discuss the topic?
2. Is there any advice on what to do?

Comment: Is this a new job, or you relocated within the same organization?

Comment: @SouravGhosh A relocation within the same organisation, i have amended the post

Comment: Thanks. One more question : `My company agreed.....` - verbally or in writing?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Assuming you mean the weighting and not the move itself, I have it unofficially (not in a letter from HR) in writing (via a DM from my LM) in a conversation saying it would happen and be discussed.

Comment: Yeah, I meant the weighting, thanks.

Comment: Have you moved already? You could always refuse to move.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I have moved already

Comment: I know this doesn't help much now, but this is a prime example of why you should get the explicit details in writing (paper/electronic) before committing to something. I hope you manage to sort something out.

Comment: @Smock Agreed, it was something I was pushing for, I gave them 2 months notice of when I intended to move. In the end it took 10 weeks before actually showing me something from that date. No matter how much I asked and reiterated the date, nothing happened.

Comment: @Smock Yes, the move was always going to happen and then we found a place and focused it around that so it was difficult to refuse or we would have lost the house. I did say that we where looking then again when we found one to give them a definitive date.

Comment: @Smock Perhaps I should put that in the question?

Comment: @Smock I have added more context

Comment: @Smock I had planned to move cities before taking the job, discussed this with them in the interview stages and they where happy with this and then got offered the job. 10 months later the move happened.

Comment: @Smock Ah i see! Ive just edited it, hope this is better

Answer (score 3):

Given the fact that the paycheck revision (weighting, as you said) was agreed upon, but no fixed (or minimum) amount was promised, the organization is free to choose the amount thy are willing to offer.

You are also free to either accept the revision and continue, or find a new job where your expectations are met.

You need to take your call: Whether to continue with the current salary or find a new job.

> *In around 1-2 weeks I have my appraisal and I have a feeling that this will be brought up as it will be the official platform that they will have to tell me about the increase in the presence of HR.*

Put forward your expectations. Do not go into details of your research and how much you "should be" getting: express your expectations from the point of view of your contribution and value addition to the organization.

- If they match it (agree to revise the revision), very good.
- Otherwise, brush up your resume and look for opportunities elsewhere to have your expectations matched.

Reality is: no matter how much you love the job / work, if you're not happy with the benefits, you're not going to stay satisfied / focused for long.

Comment: In future, the OP should negotiate not just "a weighting", but the specific value of that weighting.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica thats a good point, and I did try to do that, but the company where dragging their feet on a deadline so in the end I had no choice but to move before hand

Comment: @UIO The fact that they were dragging their feet to give you a number or deadline for a situation like this should have been a first red flag, indicating they might never have intended to raise your salary by too much.
This might be looking into it a bit too much but a company that goes this lightly over a situation like yours, possibly impacting your life standard (not sure what the proper English word is), doesn't sound like one that would be worth investing time and effort into.

Comment: @Blub In hindsight thats a good point

Answer (score 0):

This is a "lesson" for you. Next time you have to ask more questions and politely insist on writing all agreements on "paper" **before** moving on. You may think that this will be considered strange by your boss or HR. Maybe, but at least you'll be safe. When it comes to money, don't joke with it.

Just like you said, the salary weighting is very unclear. I would negotiate real numbers such as +10k salary raise or at least from +5k to +15k raise.

How to handle the situation?

1. Try to explain your problem and clarify it. For example, you gave me
   +2,000 raises, but it's too low for this expensive city. My living expenses have risen by 20%, but you only gave me a raise of 10%. Your
   employer must clearly understand why you are not satisfied with the current raise.
2. polish your resume and find other opportunities.